# How to use springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query to find all results between two dates ignoring time

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am struggling with such a simple task and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Based on personal research, it seems I am coding what I am supposed to in order to search all records between two dates using Spring Data. As far as I understood, "@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)" does the "magic".

Repository

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Temporal;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mybank.accountmanagement.model.Transaction;

    @Repository
    public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long> {
    
        
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE account_id=:idAccount AND CAST(created_at AS date) BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Transaction> findByAccountIdWithCreationDateBetween(@Param("idAccount") Long idAccount,
        @Param("fromDate") @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) Date fromDate,
        @Param("toDate") @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) Date toDate);
        
    }
```

Models:

Transaction

```
package com.mybank.accountmanagement.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction  extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    @JsonProperty("accoout_id")
    private Account account;

    @NotNull
    @NumberFormat(pattern = "#,###,###,###.##")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @NotNull
    private int transactionType;

    
    
    
    public Transaction(Account account, @NotNull BigDecimal amount, @NotNull int transactionType) {
        super();
        this.account = account;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    public void setTransactionType(int transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }

    
}
```

AuditModel

```
package com.mybank.accountmanagement.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdAt", "updatedAt" }, allowGetters = true)
public abstract class AuditModel implements Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

What I was expcting to return when searching with "fromDate":"2020-08-02", "toDate":"2020-08-02"

[image: postgres admin]

But it is returning no record at all

*** Edited

For some unknown reason for me, my records with exact date matching fromDate and toDate are token off from result

1. Searching with longer fromDate and toDate

   curl --location --request GET 'localhost:2000/transaction/1/bankstatement' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
   "fromDate":"2020-08-01",
   "toDate":"2020-08-03"
   }'

brings two records:

```
[
    {
        "createdAt": "2020-08-02T16:29:08.085+00:00",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-02T16:29:08.085+00:00",
        "id": 1,
        "amount": 1.00,
        "transactionType": 2,
        "accoout_id": 1
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2020-08-02T16:29:11.185+00:00",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-02T16:29:11.185+00:00",
        "id": 2,
        "amount": 2.00,
        "transactionType": 1,
        "accoout_id": 1
    }
]
```

so far so good

2. now I get a problem while searching with exact date. I would expect same result from above query

   curl --location --request GET 'localhost:2000/transaction/1/bankstatement' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
   "fromDate":"2020-08-02",
   "toDate":"2020-08-02"
   }'

brings no result at all

[image: no results]

*** edited. Thanks to sample provided by Kavithakaran Kanapathippillai, I noticed  that it works with new Date or 2020-08-02T00:00:00.000+00:00 but it fails with 2020-08-02. I am still lost why it fails with 2020-08-02 since I don't care about time and also it works if try one day less: 2020-08-01

Controller

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mybank.accountmanagement.BankStatementFilter;

import com.mybank.accountmanagement.model.Transaction;
import com.mybank.accountmanagement.repository.TransactionRepository;
import com.mybank.accountmanagement.service.TransactionService;

@RestController
public class TransactionController {

    @Autowired
    TransactionService transactionService;

    @Autowired
    TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    @GetMapping("/transaction/{accountId}/bankstatement")
    public List<Transaction> bankStatement(@PathVariable(value = "accountId") Long accountId,
            @Valid @RequestBody BankStatementFilter bankStatementFilter) {

        return transactionRepository.findByAccountIdWithCreationDateBetween(accountId,
                bankStatementFilter.getFromDate(), bankStatementFilter.getToDate());
    }

}
```

A simple Pojo used only to get new Date from the string sent by client (ex. Postman or curl)

```
import java.util.Date;

public class BankStatementFilter {
    
    private Date fromDate;
    private Date toDate;
    public Date getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }
    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }
    public Date getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }
    public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }

}
```

It smells some stupid thing done from my part with this POJO BankStatementFilter

Here is what I noted while comparing new Date() with 2020-08-02. Since I don't care about time, isn't that correctly?

[image: new time versus 2020-08-02]

*** Final comment

It is working now. I changed my POJO to bellow. If I am doing some silly thing I will be thanks for advice. BTW, my original question was 100% answered.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class BankStatementFilter {

    private Date fromDate;
    private Date toDate;

    public Date getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {

        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

        try {
            this.fromDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(fromDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Date getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }

    public void setToDate(String toDate) {
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

        try {
            this.toDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(toDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing right now? Is your query doesn't give you right output? Can you please add what output you are getting right now? Your query seems fine to me. Hope you will try to explain your problem more clearly in question.

Comment: Thanks. I guess there are 2 issues: (1) I missused @Temporal. (2) It is excluding records with exact date in fromDate and toDate. I will add more info above now

Comment: Did you check database and application use same timezone or not ? because data for created_at in database and reponse are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `@Temporal.Date` does not have any impact on your spring data repository method. It has impact only when it is annotated in the entity.
- Instead do the following to `cast` your parameters too:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE account_id=:idAccount " +
            "AND CAST(created_at AS date) " +
            "BETWEEN CAST(:fromDate AS date) AND CAST(:toDate AS date)"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    List<Transaction> findBy(@Param("idAccount") Long idAccount,
                             @Param("fromDate") Date fromDate,
                             @Param("toDate") Date toDate);
```

- Here is sample project which I set up with your entity except `account` as it is not in the question if you like to compare. You can import the project as maven into IntelliJ and run the main application, it will insert data and bring it back

  https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stackoverflow-63212441

Comment: Firstly, thanks. I didn't know "@Temporal.Date does not have any impact on your spring data repository method". As far as I remenber I followed an example using also @Temporal in Spring Data Repository. It seems I lost some point. Secondly, what I have to do in order to include the records matching the date also. I mean, suposing there is records with date 2020-08-02 and in my filter fromDate is 2020-08-02 and toDate is also 2020-08-02. Using your answer it is not bringing the records that are the exact date, I will add two prints to show what I mean

Comment: I actually setup a sample project with your code and I inserted to a record for sometime today and ran the query and it picked up the record.

Comment: Your sample project was very helpfull to bring me a bell. You are using new Date() while my controller is receiving exactly "2020-02-08" from client (PostMan/curl). Now I guess I am messing up something with date serialization instead of Spring Data. I just gave a try sending from PostMan to Controller Endpoint "fromDate":"2020-08-02T00:00:00.000+00:00",
    "toDate":"2020-08-02T23:59:59.062+00:00" and it worked perfectly. Well, not clear yet what is wrong since I want to ignore time and only use day. This is what I expected from BETWEEN CAST(:fromDate AS date) AND CAST(:toDate AS date)

Comment: Even if you send `2020-08-08`, it need to create a java date object. The best option is to printout the date object received inside the controller

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using >= and <= in the SQL query, in my case that works as expected.

Also my advice would be to not use native query and try using model class for quick and correct Deserialization in your case since you have the model class defined.

Comment: thanks. Kindly, can you extend your statement a bit more "not use native query and try using model class for quick and correct Deserialization in your case since you have the model class defined", It seems you are sugesting a different approach than above for a good reason. If I just replace "nativeQuery = true" by "nativeQuery = false" would I follow your advice (I guess not)

Comment: replace your query as:

@Query(value = "SELECT TRANSACTION ts FROM TRANSACTIONS ts WHERE ts.accountId=:idAccount AND CAST(created_at AS date) BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate ", nativeQuery = false)

Read the difference and implementation from here[link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)

Please upvote and accept anwser if it worked for you

Comment: I believe my issue ins't with Spring Data. Instead, it is somehow related to date conversion. I will add also the controller who calls the repository